# Spock Power Mock does not return value specified in .thenAnswer { } method

Tags: java, groovy, spock, powermock

I've a class which has `public static void` method. This method uses a method which is in different class and this method takes two arguments and  returns a `List` of values.

```
public class FirstClass {
    public static void doSomething() {
        List<String> values = SecondClass.getOrderedValuesBy(anotherMethod());
        // action 
    }

    private static String anotherMethod() {
        // some action
        return ""; // something that depends on action above.
    }
}
```

```
public class SecondClass {
    public static List<String> getOrderedValuesBy(String by) {
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        values.addAll(getOrderedValuesBy(by, true));
        return values;
    }

    private static List<String> getOrderedValuesBy(String by, boolean ordered) {
       // some action
    }
}
```

Then when writing some tests for that I use `mockStatic` method on the `SecondClass` and initialize the `FirstClass` as a new object as below.

```
def "someTest"() {
    given:
    mockStatic(SecondClass)
    FirstClass firstClass = new FirstClass()
    when(SecondClass.getOrderedValuesBy(anyString()).thenAnswer {['some values'])}
}
```

it does not return these values I would like to have, because I need them in some private method that are used called in `doSomething()` void method and as parameter, these method takes `values` list. Do someone have any ideas what I do wrong, and how I could manipulate the values returned by this method called in the void method in `FirstClass`

Comment: You need to use `.thenReturn` instead of `.thenAnswer`, since you want to return a value.  `.thenAnswer` is used to run additional code before providing a return value.

Comment: @Jordan it seems to be working, thank you!

Comment: @Jordan, please turn your comment into an answer the OP can accept in order to close the question. And please also explain why `thenAnswer` would not work if used correctly. It can also return a value, even though it might be a bit over-engineered using it here.

Comment: I even tried by myself now, `thenAnswer` works nicely. The problem must have been somewhere else.

Comment: @Gstark, you asked a question, I answered it. I would appreciate some feedback. This is what polite people usually do on SO. So please check my answer, then accept + upvote if you think it is correct (I certainly do).

Answer (score 0):

You can use both `thenReturn` or `thenAnswer`, it depends on what you want to do before returning a value, as *@Jordan* said. Here is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

**Application classes:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q59993907;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SecondClass {
  public static List<String> getOrderedValuesBy(String by) {
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    values.addAll(getOrderedValuesBy(by, true));
    return values;
  }

  private static List<String> getOrderedValuesBy(String by, boolean ordered) {
    // some action
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add("one");
    result.add("two");
    result.add("three");
    return result;
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q59993907;

import java.util.List;

public class FirstClass {
  public static void doSomething() {
    List<String> values = SecondClass.getOrderedValuesBy(anotherMethod());
    // action
    System.out.println(values);
  }

  private static String anotherMethod() {
    // some action
    return ""; // something that depends on action above.
  }
}
```

**Spock specification using PowerMockito:**

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q59993907

import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunnerDelegate
import org.spockframework.runtime.Sputnik
import spock.lang.Specification

import static de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q59993907.SecondClass.getOrderedValuesBy
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyString
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(Sputnik)
@PrepareForTest(SecondClass)
class PowerMockStaticTest extends Specification {
  static final PrintStream originalSysOut = System.out
  PrintStream mockSysOut = Mock()

  def setup() {
    System.out = mockSysOut
  }

  def cleanup() {
    System.out = originalSysOut
  }

  def "no mock"() {
    when:
    FirstClass.doSomething()

    then:
    1 * mockSysOut.println(['one', 'two', 'three'])
  }

  def "when-thenAnswer"() {
    given:
    mockStatic(SecondClass)
    when(getOrderedValuesBy(anyString())).thenAnswer { ['thenAnswer'] }

    when:
    FirstClass.doSomething()

    then:
    1 * mockSysOut.println(['thenAnswer'])
  }

  def "when-thenReturn"() {
    given:
    mockStatic(SecondClass)
    when(getOrderedValuesBy(anyString())).thenReturn(['thenReturn'])

    when:
    FirstClass.doSomething()

    then:
    1 * mockSysOut.println(['thenReturn'])
  }
}
```

Comment: Update: I added when-then blocks with actual condition checking to the test instead of relying checking console output manually.